# JavaScript or jQuery regex method and statement to validate a sting is yyyy-mm-dd and one the is hh:mm AM/PM

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am no good with regex so I am not even going to pretend. What I want to do is validate a string as being numerical and in the following format `yyyy-mm-dd`, and another likewise but for time `hh:mm AM/PM`

Trying on google best I can find is for `mm-dd-yyyy` ,  `mm/dd/yyyy`.

So could anyone be kind enough to help me out here for the two types of patterns I need?
Also whats the best means to compare the pattern with the string? is it `.test()` or `.match()` or something else?

Comment: Since you found for those patterns, it wouldn't be that tough to mould it accordingly. What have you tried?

Comment: Java regex is pretty close to javascript. You can use this tool to play with regex and see what they match. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @LeeMeador Why use the Java version when the page you linked has a JavaScript one as well? http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is for date:

```
/^[0-9]{4}-(((0[13578]|(10|12))-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$/.test(date);
```

This is for time:

```
/^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9]){1}(:[0-5][0-9] [AP][M]){1}$/.test(time);
```

**REF:** From the [very first](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5) Google result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but since I've tried [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) I never had problems with dates, it's definitily worth a look.